# IBM mobilefirst 7.1 - javascript error logs

Tags: logging, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing an hybrid application. Logs are correctly send the mfp if we explicitly write them. However if the application crash due to an Javascript error, no logs is send.
Consequently, those logs disappeared since it is not reported by the application either (Xcode). 
Does MFP provide tools for this kind of errors ?

Comment: When you say "logs are sent", what does that mean? Are you sending to Analytics? ?

Comment: Actually i am a little bit confuse between WL.Logger and WL.Analytics. But the final goal is to be able to track unexpected javascript error from mfp server ...

Comment: WL.Logger and WL.Analytics are little similar, but the difference in forwarding the log to the analytics. In WL.Logger, you can filter out the client logs with various log levels and same can either stopped or forwarded to analytics. But in case WL.Analytics it is the logging where we can send the custom Data to Analytics from your app. This customData can be used to create additional custom charts on Analytics console